# AWE memory configuration

Tags: windows-server-2003, oracle9i

I am configuring Oracle 9i to make use of AWE memory configuration on Windows 32-bit.

I am facing error 
ORA-27102: out of memory
OSD-00022: Message 22 not found; product=RDBMS; facility=SOSD

**Additional Details**
OS: Windows 2003 Server Enterprise Edition 32 BIT
Oracle: Oracle 9.2.0.1.0 Enterprise Edition

- Server CPU Count: 16
- Server Ram: 32GB

**Boot.ini**

```
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Windows Server 2003, Enterprise" /noexecute=optout /fastdetect /PAE
```

**Registry**

AWE_WINDOW_MEMORY: 1384120320

**Oracle Settings**

- *.aq_tm_processes=1
- *.background_dump_dest='C:\oracle\admin\ORCL\bdump'
- ### *.compatible='9.2.0.0.0'

  *.control_files='C:\oracle\oradata\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL','C:\oracle\oradata\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL','C:\oracle\oradata\ORCL\CONTROL03.CTL'
- *.core_dump_dest='C:\oracle\admin\ORCL\cdump'
- *.db_block_buffers=480000
- *.db_block_size=8192
- *._db_block_lru_latches=32
- *.db_domain=''
- *.db_file_multiblock_read_count=16
- *.db_name='ORCL'
- *.dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=ORCLXDB)'
- *.fast_start_mttr_target=300
- *.hash_join_enabled=TRUE
- *.instance_name='ORCL'
- *.java_pool_size=33554432
- *.job_queue_processes=10
- *.large_pool_size=8388608
- *.open_cursors=300
- *.pga_aggregate_target=117922508
- *.processes=150
- *.query_rewrite_enabled='FALSE'
- *.remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'
- *.shared_pool_size=354121647
- *.sort_area_size=524288
- *.star_transformation_enabled='FALSE'
- *.timed_statistics=TRUE
- *.undo_management='AUTO'
- *.undo_retention=10800
- *.undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'
- *.use_indirect_data_buffers=TRUE
- *.user_dump_dest='C:\oracle\admin\ORCL\udump'

What I have tried, is to decrease the AWE_WINDOW_MEMORY to 400M, also I tried to increase to 2 GB but in both scenario I receive the not enough memory error, so my first question is to confirm my AWE_WINDOW_MEMORY is really taking effect?
Please help

Comment: Please share with us your findings from your own research. What have you already tried?

Comment: First I am not a DBA, what I am trying here is to increase the SGA more than 1.6 GB which is the max I can set without VLM change. So I am trying to enable the VLM and increase the oracle to make use of  the available RAM space which is 32 GB. I tried reducing the AWE Memory to 400 M, increase to 2GB but I always get the not enough memory error. So I suspect either my awe_window_memory is still not considered or my pfile settings consume more than what is allowed but I can't figure out.

Comment: The obligatory "get rid of old software and use 64-bit" comment.